# Finding the Count per field for a Window using Flux Query - InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb, flux-influxdb

I am trying to display data where it aggregates by a field and displays count per a window. I'm struggling coming up with the syntax.  Let's assume this is my data in InfluxDb:

```html
import "array"

data = array.from(rows: [
  {application: "ap1", time: "2022-10-01T10:10:06.757Z", message: "error..."},
  {application: "ap2", time: "2022-10-03T15:11:05.757Z", message: "error..."},
  {application: "ap1", time: "2022-10-02T12:11:08.757Z", message: "error..."},
  {application: "ap1", time: "2022-10-04T13:13:05.757Z", message: "error..."},
  {application: "ap3", time: "2022-10-05T10:11:16.757Z", message: "error..."},
  {application: "ap3", time: "2022-10-06T15:22:05.757Z", message: "error..."},
])

data
 |> group(columns: ["application", "time"])
```

I'd like to group by results like this:

[image]

The window could be...show count per application type...per hour, per day, or per week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with the [count](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/universe/count/) function.

Answer (score 0):

Group data by `application` column and then use [aggregateWindow](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/universe/aggregatewindow/) with desired time interval and [count](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/universe/count/) function.

Eg.

```js
data
 |> map(fn: (r) => ({ r with _time: time(v: r.time) }))
 |> range(start: 2022-10-01T00:00:00Z)
 |> group(columns: ["application"])
 |> aggregateWindow(every: 1mo, fn: count, column: "message", createEmpty: false)
```

Output:

```
2022-10-13T12:29:14.412Z  ap1  3
2022-10-13T12:29:14.412Z  ap2  1
2022-10-13T12:29:14.412Z  ap3  2
```

When you query data from a bucket, some columns are provided by default, like `_time` and `_value`, so there would be no need for extra time mapping call like in the example above and you could also omit `column` arg to `aggregateWindow()` as it operates on `_value` column by default.